# In .NET development, what is the breakdown of WinForms/desktop developers versus ASP.NET developers?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wpf, vb.net, winforms

What is the proportion of .NET developers who do WinForms/desktop development vs ASP.NET development? Is there very much overlap? Are they very different skill-sets?

Comment: I do both. Primarily ASP.NET, but when I need to supplement an app with automation or something else, I jump to Class Libraries or Console Apps. There really isn't that much difference between any of them.

Comment: There seems to be more taboos on this site than political websites from my old communists country home. I;m actually feeling a bit of fear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess-timate is that it's probably a 60/40 split in favor of web development.  But I think a more interesting trend is that both the web and windows camps are seeing significant schisms.

Windows definitely is definitely splitting along the WPF and non-WPF lines, since WPF presents such a different UI model.  WPF is still a small percentage of Windows developers, but it's definitely gaining some ground.  I'd guess that WPF probably only makes up 10-20 percent of Windows development.

Web development may be more interesting as you not only have the Silverlight split going on, but you also have the MVC split happening.  Traditional ASP.NET development is still king, but MVC definitely is gaining significant traction and Silverlight is becoming a powerful niche.  Maybe a 60-25-15 split among ASP.NET, MVC and Silverlight respectively -- which isn't bad at all for relatively new technologies.

There are definitely overlapping areas of skill across these areas (biz tier and data tier development, along with WCF services), but the UI development paradigm is very different.  Having a windows forms developer switch over to an asp.net web form project will require a bit of a learning curve if it's his/her first web form project.

I'm basing my guess-timates on what I see in my regional user group communities and discussions with some leaders in those communities.  Definitely not scientific.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how accurate it is but [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=523cb099-bc1c-4ea4-abaf-21a6c73ec00e) did an informal survey.

Comment: I suspect that the results of that survey are quite heavily skewed in favour of newer technologies by the nature of Scott Hanselman's audience.

Comment: @Carson Skewed in favour of web too. I know I stopped reading his blog because there was so much stuff about ASP.Net. Just checked, 137 pages of posts tagged ASP.Net, 9 pages of posts tagged WPF, no WinForms tag at all.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably going to get closed in the next 10 minutes, so I'll answer quickly. I doubt there is a clean distinction between the two. I know at my own place of employment, most developers work on both.

And the two skill sets are probably not as distinct as you might think. Both ASP.Net apps and WIndows applications could require large amounts of C# code, WCF perhaps and some amount of database work. These skills would be required for either type of development.

Comment: Why shoud it be closed? Some fundamental knowledge of trends can be of great value

Comment: @user370401 Unfortunately questions aren't closed based on value. :(

Comment: @user370401 questions that involve comparing one technology or language to another need to be *very* carefully worded; doubly so when it is a question about the people who use them. Compare my version of your question to yours.

Comment: Maybe I should just look at the number of questions tagged with asp.net vs winforms/wpf. I'm a CS graduate and I'm trying to systematically learn asp.net before applying for my first .Net job. Not having to venture into Winforms would have saved my 40% of the time I guess? My opinion is majority of the work tend to come from asp.net track.

Comment: @Rex M +1 for your version of the question!

Answer (score 1):

This has about 10 seconds before it becomes community wiki or is closed, but I suggest looking at the job listings in your area to get a sense of what the market is looking for.  With WPF, you can sort of flip back and forth between Silverlight or Windows apps, and ASP.NET webforms was originally designed with an event model that was supposed to closely mimic Winforms... but the reality is that there are major differences in architecture strategies that generally make fat-client developers unable to develop good web apps and vice-versa.  The stateless nature of HTTP, coupled with the HTML/JavaScript/CSS trifecta is just a different beast than the Windows app market.  I have a strong suspicion that the employment demand favors web developers over Windows devs as well, unless you're in the gaming industry.  But that's not really a market .NET has really thrived in anyway.